# How to get count value increamented within loop

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/KKH9a/16/

Tried using console using `table1.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML` => `"Numbers"`
Tried even this code `table1.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML!=null` => `true`

But if I try this code below:

HTML:

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td>Value</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < table1.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table1.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML; j++) {
        if (table1.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML != null) {
            var count = 0;
            count = count + 1;
            alert(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `table1` variable you're using isn't defined, for starters.

Comment: `j < table1.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML`? Do you realize that the value of the `innerHTML` depends on the value of `j`, there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `table1` isn't defined. You need to use `document.getElementById` to get a reference to your table element.
2. On line 2 you're specifying `j < table1.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML`. This doesn't make any sense and should be changed to `j < table1.rows[i].cells.length`.
3. You need to move your `count` variable completely outside your loop, otherwise it will always be equal to 1.

Change your code to this:

```
var table1 = document.getElementById('table1');
var count=0;

for(var i=0;i<table1.rows.length;i++)
{
    for(var j=0;j<table1.rows[i].cells.length;j++)
    {
        if(table1.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML!=null)
        {
            count++;
            alert(count);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKH9a/26/).

Comment: var table1 = document.getElementById('tablerecords');
 var count=0;

 for(var i=0;i<table1.rows.length;i++)
 {     
      if(table1.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML!="")
      {
      count++;
      }     
    }
 alert(count);
}

Comment: @user3047780 no worries. Remember to mark this as the accepted answer when you get the chance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Work on understanding how Javascript interacts with the HTML DOM.

At present your code refers to "table1", but this has nothing to do with the HTML element with the id "table1".

Introductory Javascript tutorials will explain how to get DOM elements into variables. To make things easier, you could use JQuery or something similar.

Once you're past that, you can start looking at the errors in your for loop logic (which other answers have already addressed).

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't use innerHTML to check if there is something in a node. Just count the number of childs instead :

```
if (table1.rows[i].cells[j].childNodes.length > 0) {
```

Secondly, if you declare `count` inside the loops, it will be resetted at each iteration.

Thirldy, I don't understand what you're trying to do with `j < table1.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML`. And `innerHTML` is a String, not a number. You should use parseInt on it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice bro.. :) Just was first time working in it. took time to get correctly according to my way... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate count of cells using JQuery after document is ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $('#table1 td').each(function() {
        if($(this).html() != "") {
            count++;
        }
    });
    alert(count);
});
```

Updated Demo: `http://jsfiddle.net/KKH9a/27/`